# Python3 re.split() via character which is not in special substring

Tags: python-3.x, tokenize

I'm trying to parse and validate language. I want to tokenize input to check grammar.
My input string is:

```
something > 0 AND (something CONTAINS "substr" OR NOT something)
```

if i did this:

```
tokens = re.split(r"([\s()])", input)
```

i got this:

```
['something', ' ', '>', ' ', '0', ' ', 'AND', ' ', '', '(', 'something', ' ', 'CONTAINS','   ', '"substr"', ' ', 'OR', ' ', 'NOT', ' ', 'something', ')', '']
```

which is exacly what i want. But, there is allways "something". If i replace **"substr"** with **"substr with whitespace"**, i got this array, which is not the perfect result:

```
['"substr', ' ', 'with', ' ', 'whitespace"']
```

Is there any way how to split to following?

```
['"substr with whitespace"']
```

Or how to efficiently repair this "so close split" ?
Or maybe something different which i missed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think an split with

```
re.split(r"\s*(NOT|AND|OR|\(|\)|CONTAINS|<|>|=)\s*", input)
```

solved my problem